# Porto theme issue in magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3.2, php-7.2

I have created the local setup from the live server. After that, I have copied the theme files like Porto and porto_rtl from the live server and pasted it on the local setup.

Then run all the command. but it throwing the js error

> Compilation from source
>   /var/www/html/test//app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/web/js/jquery.parallax.min.js
>   failed Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File\NotFoundException: Unable to
>   resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/Smartwave/porto_rtl/en_US/js/jquery.parallax.min.js' in
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php:160

How to resolved that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to theme directory or theme vendor name is renamed.
Try below step to fix this.

1. Change your theme vendor first letter in capitol.
2. Change the theme directory name into theme's.

   > ```
   > app\design\frontend\<Your-Vendor>\<theme-name>\composer.json
   > app\design\frontend\<Your-Vendor>\<theme-name>\theme.xml  (if parent theme is not default magento)
   > app\design\frontend\<Your-Vendor>\<theme-name>\registration.php
   > ```
3. Now, delete your current theme entry from the "**theme**" table, but
   keep back-up of this table before removing custom theme entry
4. Now run the command for setup-upgrade, static content deploy, and
   cache clear.

   > ```
   > rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/*
   >
   > php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   > php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   > php bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento c:c
   > ```
5. Now you will not see the compilation error
6. Now you will see new entry into the "**theme**" database table
7. Change your store theme from admin

Thank you